# How to pass the end of the URL to a Value=“”

Tags: asp.net, .net

i want to pass value to URL and that value from session...
i m using following syntax...

```
<a href="Registration.aspx?UserID=<%Convert.ToInt32(Session["userid"]); %>">link</a>
```

so what is the solution???

Comment: not working...
following error given...
"Input string was not in a correct format."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `onvert.ToInt32`

The url doesn't mind what type it is.Eventually - it's   a string.

Try this :

`<a href='Registration.aspx?UserID=<%=Session["userid"].ToString() %>'>link</a>`

Safer way :

`<a href='Registration.aspx?UserID=<%=Session["userid"]+"" %>'>link</a>`